# How to define a custom gradient in pytorch with an optimizer?

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch

I am trying to learn an embedding with a custom gradient function. Basically, I have an embedding

```
my_embedding = torch.nn.Embedding(
                  num_embeddings=n,
                  embedding_dim=d)
```

and an optimizer, for instance

```
my_optimizer = torch.optim.SGD(
                  my_embedding.parameters(),
                  lr=0.01)
```

I am computing some gradient manually (denoted as `my_gradient` below) and I am doing `my_embedding.weight.grad = my_gradient`.
However, when I'm doing `my_optimizer.step()` it does not update anything.
Am I missing something ? (in this case, I could directly skip the optimizer but I would like to understand why it's not working)

Comment: You should provide a complete example. Without the example, it is hard to know what went wrong exactly.